# How to set custom data picker like date picker?

Tags: android

How to set custom data picker in android like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create layout with a list view like below...

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/sample_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:divider="DrawableResource/HEXColor"
android:background="DrawableResource/HEXColor"
android:padding="10dp"/>
```

And create a list item according to your data type like TextView or ImageView

I'm not adding import statements...

```
public class PicData {
        public interface setDataSelectedListener{
        public void onDataSelected(YourDataType data);
        }
        List<YourDataType> list;
        Context con;
        ListView lv;
        LayoutInflator lf;
        setDataSelectedListener listener;
        AlertDialog ad;
        public PicData(Context c, List<YourDataType> l,setDataSelectedListener sl){
        this.list=l;
        this.con=c;
        this.listener=sl;
        lf=(LayoutInflator)con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATOR_SERVICE);
        View v=lf.inflate(R.layout.your_layout,null);
        lv=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.sample_list);
        lv.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View v1, ViewGroup vg){
        if(v1==null)v1=lf.inflate(R.layout.item_layout,null);
        YourChildView child=v1.findViewById(R.id.child_id);
        /*Here you have to set your data like...
        child.setText(list.get(pos)); if it is TextView
        child.setImageBitmap(list.get(pos)); if it is ImageView
        */
        return v1;
        }
        @Override
        public YourDataType getItem(int pos){
        return list.get(pos);
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int pos){
        return pos;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount(){
        return list.size();
        }
        });
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v2, int pos1, long ll){
        listener.onDataSelected(list.get(pos1);
        });
        AlertDialog.Builder bd=new AlerDialog.BUilder(con);
        bd.setTitle("Pick Data");
        bd.setView(v);
        ad=bd.create();
        }
        protected void show(){
        ad.show:
        }
        }
```

In your activity add like below...

```
GetData gd=new GetData(this,YourDataTypeList,new GetData.setDataSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataSelected(YourDataType data){
    //Do your work here...
    }
    });
```

You can customize above code as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing library  [CarouselPicker](https://github.com/GoodieBag/CarouselPicker)

It supports both icon and text fields.

Comment: This site can’t be reached.